# Printing values of one array based on the values of another

Tags: python, arrays, string, printing, boolean

I'm trying to print out the times at which each one of these court is available based on a Boolean table, however, the times corresponding to each Boolean value are held in another table. So my question is how do I print the values from one table based on the table of another.
Here's the code so far:

```
times = {
  "times1": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
  "times2": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
  "times3": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
  "times4": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
  "times5": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
  "times6": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
  "times7": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"],
  "times8": ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"]
access = {
  "access1": [True,False,False,True,True,False,False,False,True,True],
  "access2": [False,False,True,True,False,False,False,False,True,True],
  "access3": [False,False,False,True,True,False,True,False,True,False],
  "access4": [True,True,False,True,True,True,False,False,True,True],
  "access5": [True,False,False,True,True,False,False,False,True,False],
  "access6": [True,False,False,True,True,False,True,True,False,True],
  "access7": [True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False,True,True],
  "access8": [True,False,True,True,False,False,False,False,True,True]
  for i in access:
    if access[i] == False:
      print(times[i])
```

if access is False than the time corresponding to the position of that Boolean value should be printed

Comment: `access[i]` is a list, not True or False.

Answer (score 0):

You're only iterating through the dictionary, not the list of values in each dictionary entry. So `access[i]` will be a list of booleans, not one of the boolean values, and the comparison with `False` will always fail.

You need nested loops.

```
for a, t in zip(access.values(), times.values()):
    for a1, t1 in zip(a, t):
        if not a1:
            print(t1, end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work but it prints the results vertically rather than horizontally, do you know how to change this?

Comment: I changed it so that each list is printed horizontally, and it starts a new line for each list.

Comment: I am sorry if I am ask too much but is there a way for the result to only be printed once as the current results repeat themselves eight times (I assume this is because of the 8 different arrays in the dictionary)

Comment: You could put the times in a set, and check if the time is already in the set before printing it again.

Comment: Or just put the times in the set in the loop and print the set at the end.